# Does getComputedStyle, in IE9, always return pixel values?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, pixel

According to the first image on this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a getComputedStyle().height call may not always resolve to pixels. From my tests with px, em ,ex and %, it always resolves to pixels.

Can someone give me an example where it doesn't resolve to pixels?

Thanks

**ETA:** I've just chanced on a property that doesn't return pixels. If 'left' is set to 'auto', getComputedStyle returns 'auto'. No idea why. It'd be nice if there was some documentation I could check so I'd know when to use one of the offset members instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case for hidden elements (with `display: none`) or their parents.

Comment: Is it just a bad choice of words then saying that the height may not always resolve to pixels? This implies that it may resolve to some other unit.